# Howto remove elements from a List which are "lower" than specified element

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a `List<String>` which I sorted alphabetically using `Collections.sort(...)`. Now I have a reference `String` and I want to remove all Strings from the `List` which are "lower" (in the alphabetical ordering) than my reference String. Is there any nice way to do that or should I go through the List one by one and comparing each record to the reference value myself?

**EDIT:**
Since someone had asked for working solution here it is. `originalList` is `List<String>` ... duplicities will be lost with this solution

```
String filterString = "...";
TreeSet<String> tSet = new TreeSet<String>(originalList);
List<String> filteredResources = new ArrayList<String>(tSet.tailSet());
```

Comment: What happens with duplicated item in the original list. I am afraid that these duplicated items will NOT be present in the tailset.

Comment: Yes, see the EDIT in the question, it is there from February 2011 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no duplicates, then you can do this:

1. Create a TreeSet using the [TreeSet constructor that takes a collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Collection%29)
2. Now simply call [TreeSet.tailSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet%28java.lang.Object%29)(refString)

Comment: can you post how you solved it using a working example so that it can be handy for further reference.(+1 for tailSet)

Comment: kevin i do understand.but i asked for a example.

Comment: I added it to the quiestion itself.

Answer (score 0):

Once it's sorted it would be trivial using a [ListIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to iterate the list and perform the comparison. Once you're comparison misses, you know you can stop the iteration since your list was sorted.

Note though, that sorting is a relatively expensive operation, hence it would be more efficient to just iterate the list from start to end performing your comparison.

---

You could also employ an algorithm which checks the middle (`list.size()/2`) element, then moves up or down again halfing the resultset, and so on until you've found the converging point.

E.g. looking for `"f"` with a list `{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}` would perform comparisons on middle element `"d"`, then look at the middle `"f"` element of the second half `{"e", "f", "g"}` where a match is immediately found and the algorithm can stop.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the best way I can think of.

1. Sort the list
2. Start going through the list one by one, starting from the lowest.
3. Reach a point until the list element is higher than the one you have.
4. Break out of the loop.
5. Keep a note of this index and split the list using subList function by this index.

Comment: -1 because this style of solution should at least use binary search (O(log N)).